# Google Chart Combo graph sees 100 as 0.1

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a strange issue with a google chart combo graph. I have a € values on one axis and % on the other. Everything works fine until the point where the % values go over 100. The graph is by default divided like so: [working graph](http://prntscr.com/kwiq7i)

But when the value goes over 100, it changes to this: [non working graph](http://prntscr.com/kwiqln)

This is the code for my graph generation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
var options = {

  vAxis: {title: 'Value (€)'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Audit Date'},
  legend:{position: 'top', maxLines:2},
  seriesType: 'bars',
  series: {
      3: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
      4: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1}
      },
  vAxes: {
    1: {
      title:'Gross Profit %',
      textStyle: {color: 'green'}
    }
}};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

and the array is generated with results from database and then pushed into an array which is then converted into json

```
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $wastage);
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $purchases);
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $sales);
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $labour);
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $gp_per);
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

It just seems like a value of 100 is converted to 0.1 instead, but why is that happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data, when the % > 100? --> `console.log(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);`

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the chart is causing an error by increasing the percentage value over 100 which results in a blank chart.

You could try to add a max value of 100 to this since this is a percentage. This can be done by adding to the vertical axes.

```
  vAxes: {
    1: {
      title:'Gross Profit %',
      textStyle: {color: 'green'},
      maxValue: 100
    }
}};
```

For a list of configuration options such as this one, you can look towards the bottom of the page here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart